# Find the probability of forming a triangle by choosing random points from a line $AB$

Tags: probability-theory

> **Q:** Two points are chosen at random on a line $AB$, each point being chosen according to the uniform distribution on $AB$, and the choices being made independently of each other. The line $AB$ may now be regarded as divided into three parts. What is the probability that they may be made into a triangle.

**A:** Let $x,y\in(A,B)$ denote such two points, as shown below,
[image: line AB with the points x,y]

then to construct a triangle we must have that
$$\begin{cases}
\overline{Ax}+\overline{yx}\geq \overline{By}\\
\overline{Ax}+\overline{By}\geq \overline{xy}\\
\overline{By}+\overline{yx}\geq \overline{Ax}
\end{cases}\implies y\geq\frac{A+B}{2}\quad\wedge\quad x<y.$$

Let $\,T\,$ denote the event of forming a triangle, $\,L1\,$ the event that $\,y\geq\frac{A+B}{2}\,$ and $\,L2\,$ the event that $x<y\implies x<\frac{A+B}{2}$, then
$$P(T)=P(L1)P(L2).$$

But
$$P(L1)=\int_{\frac{A+B}{2}}^B \frac{1}{B-A} \, dx=\frac{1}{2}$$
and 
$$P(L2)=1-P(L1)=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
so $P(T)=1/4.$

Would this result and reasoning be correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.